# How to cancel alarmmanager in service android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I use alarmManager to control a Locationmanager for always check distance.
I use setRepeating alarm always 10 seconds (for checking)

I want to app alert only first time when user go out area (distance > 100 m)
but it alert every 10 seconds(user go out).

How to cancel when it alert at first time?

Thank you very much.

Activity

```
        trackchk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(trackchk.isChecked())
                {
                    Intent intrack = new Intent(hatebug.this,trackservice.class);
                    intrack.putExtra("LT", lattointent);
                    intrack.putExtra("LN", lontointent);

                    Calendar calendartrack = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendartrack.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    calendartrack.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
                    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("CHECKTRACK", true).commit();
                    tracklocal = PendingIntent.getService(hatebug.this, 0, intrack, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    alarmtrack = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmtrack.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendartrack.getTimeInMillis(), 6000, tracklocal);
                }
                else {
                    getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("CHECKTRACK", false).commit();
                    alarmtrack = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmtrack.cancel(tracklocal);
                }
            }
        });
```

Service (onStart)

```
public void onStart(Intent intent,int startId){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float latserv = intent.getFloatExtra("LT", 0);
        float lonserv  =intent.getFloatExtra("LN", 0);      
        String slat = String.valueOf(latserv);
        String slon = String.valueOf(lonserv);
        LocationManager locate = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location lm = locate.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        float lat = (float) lm.getLatitude();
        float lon = (float) lm.getLongitude();
        float dlat = (float) Math.toRadians(lat - latserv);
        float dlon = (float) Math.toRadians(lon - lonserv);
        float a1 = (float) ((Math.sin(dlat/2))*(Math.sin(dlat/2)));
        float a2 = (float) ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lon)))*(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(100.546652)))*(Math.sin(dlon/2))*(Math.sin(dlon/2)));
        float a = a1+a2;
        float c = (float) (2*Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)));
        float d = 6371000*c;

        String lool = String.format("Latitude\t\t: %1$s\nLongitude\t: %2$s\nDistance\t\t: %3$f",slat,slon,d);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), lool, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(d>100)
        {

                            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(1000);                     
        }
}
```

Comment: use [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: thank you. Yes. I have alarm.cancel() to stop but it cancel when app run in activity. what the way to stop alarm when user don't open this app(activity). I want to alarm stop auto after remind at first time.
Or I don't understand your answer. Please explain for me.

Comment: @user1838158 I think _you_ will have to explain why you `cancel()` your alarm in your `Activity` instead of in your `Service`?

Comment: @Class Stacker My service don't understand alarmtrack.cancel(tracklocal). It can't be resolved. And I set  alarmtrack.cancel(tracklocal) in my Activity Because user can cancel AlarmManager. But I want to my app can stop alarm after it reminds at first time. I have service to remind but I don't know the solution to stop it.

Comment: @user1838158Of course it cannot resolve the `alarmtrack` object, but it doesn't have to. Your service can simply request the AlarmManager just like your Activity does it, because it's a system wide service, so they both will see the same service. Then, all you need is a referecne to the PendingIntent which you registered. If your activities and your service run in the same process, you could share this (with a bit of caution) via an Application subclass object. Having said that, you could also share the AlarmManager reference in this way (with a bit iof caution).

Answer (score 0):

By calling [AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent operation)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Comment: Thank you but I can't put AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent operation) in my service.

Comment: @user1838158 _Why_ can't you call `cancel()` in your `Service`?

Comment: Service don't get alarmtrack.cancel(tracklocal). I should set PendingIntent in service ? However Thank you for attention.